Show that a rectangle set without its edges are also rectangles
Let $R$ be a rectangle defined as such,
$$
R = \{(x,y) : a \leq x \leq b \wedge c \leq y \leq d\}
$$
and let $R_L$ be a set that remains if we remove the left edge of rectangle R.
$$
R_L = \{(x,y) : a < x \leq b \wedge c \leq y \leq d\}
$$
How do I show that $R_L$ is also a rectangle?
Approach
A rectangle is any set congruent to the set,
$$
\{(x,y) : 0 \leq x \leq w \wedge 0 \leq y \leq h \}
$$
for $w,h \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. Two sets are said to be congruent if their points can be put in a one-to-one correspondence in such a way that distance are preserved.
$R$ is a rectangle because if we let $w = b-a$ and $h=d-c$ and let $(p_1,q_1), (p_2, q_2)$ be any two points such that $(p_1,q_1), (p_2, q_2) \in R$, then
$$
(p_1-a,q_1-c), (p_2-a, q_2-c) \in \{(x,y) : 0 \leq x \leq w \wedge 0 \leq y \leq h \}
$$
and the distance between these points is,
$$
d((p_1-a,q_1-c), (p_2-a, q_2-c))= \sqrt {(p_2-a-(p_1-a))^2 + (q_2-c - (q_1-c))^2}
$$
$$
d((p_1-a,q_1-c), (p_2-a, q_2-c)) = \sqrt {(p_2-p_1)^2 + (q_2 - q_1)^2}
$$
which is equal to the distance from $(p_1,q_1)$ to $(p_2, q_2)$. Similarly, if $(p_1-a,q_1-c), (p_2-a, q_2-c)$ are two points such that;
$$
(p_1-a,q_1-c), (p_2-a, q_2-c) \in \{(x,y) : 0 \leq x \leq w \wedge 0 \leq y \leq h \}
$$
then $(p_1,q_1), (p_2, q_2) \in R$ and like before, we can show that;
$$
d((p_1,q_1), (p_2, q_2))=d((p_1-a,q_1-c), (p_2-a, q_2-c))
$$
I tried doing this for $R_L$. Let $(p_1,q_1), (p_2, q_2)$ be any two points such that $(p_1,q_1), (p_2, q_2) \in R_L$. Then, like before we can show that;
$$
(p_1-a,q_1-c), (p_2-a, q_2-c) \in \{(x,y) : 0 \leq x \leq w \wedge 0 \leq y \leq h \}
$$
and that,
$$
d((p_1,q_1), (p_2, q_2))=d((p_1-a,q_1-c), (p_2-a, q_2-c))
$$
Problem
However, if we let $(p_1-a,q_1-c), (p_2-a, q_2-c)$ be any two points such that,
$$
(p_1-a,q_1-c), (p_2-a, q_2-c) \in \{(x,y) : 0 \leq x \leq w \wedge 0 \leq y \leq h \}
$$
then, it's not necessarily that $(p_1,q_1), (p_2, q_2) \in R_L$ (i.e., when $p_1 = a$ or $p_2 = a$). So I'm not sure how to continue from here. I don't know much about measure theory. I only know this from the book Calculus by Tom Apostol.

With your definition of rectangle, $R_L$ is not a rectangle.

Imagine your are removing boundary of a closed disk, then its not a closed disk any more, isn't it?. May be you definition rectangles as elemts in a set with all possibility with boundary. There is nothing to prove. Its by our definition.

@Wozero I see, that solves it then. thanks!
